# how to see if flask sessions = each other

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build a number guess game in Flask. Everything is working except for the `if` statement to see if the random number == the user's input. This is what I have so far. I think that I am very close.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = '1'
import random

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # session.clear()
    session['random'] = random.randrange(0,5)
    session['answer'] = request.form['answer']
    if session['answer'] == session['random']:
        return render_template('correct.html')
        print "Winner"
    else:
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template('index.html', random=session['random'], answer=session['answer'])
```

Comment: Your last `return` statement will never execute.

Comment: `random.randrange()` returns a number, but anything coming directly from a form field is going to be a string.  In Python, no number is ever equal to a string - you need to convert one to the other's type (via `int()` or `str()`) before comparing them.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

er... *code wise*, it's fine (edit: aside from trying to equate a string and a number). Logic wise... not so much.

first thing I noticed, you have a `print` after a `return` - you'll never hit that print statement.

second thing, the last `return` will never run, you have

```
if something: return ...
else: return ...
return
```

you'll always either hit the first or second `return`.

third, every time the user makes a guess, the number is changed... odds seem stacked against the user.

I think you need to differentiate between a `GET` (i.e. page load) and a `POST` (i.e. the form being submitted)

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  if request.method == 'GET':
    session['random'] = random.randrange(0,5)
    return render_template('index.html')
  elif request.method == 'POST':
    guess = int(request.form['answer'])

    if guess == session['random']: return render_template('correct.html')
    else: return redirect('/') 
  else: return redirect('/')
```